# ORA-24338: statement handle not executed (not executed)

Tags: c#

This code connect to oracle but not execute query.
I install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET.
And check code is true.
And Oracle.DataAccess.dll.
And It works query in sql developer.
And everything code is true but not execute statement .
help me.

```
bool result = false;
string connst =System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["OISCS"];
Console.Write(connst);
OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
dbConn.ConnectionString = connst;

OleDbCommand dbCom = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT * FROM OIS.USERINFo WHERE  USERID= '" + UserID + "';", dbConn);

dbCom.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
dbCom.CommandTimeout = 30;

try
{
       dbConn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = (OleDbDataReader)dbCom.ExecuteReader();
       dbReader.Read();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {               
        throw e;
 }
 return result;
```

Comment: `ExecuteReader` retursn `OleDbDataReader`. Why don't you keep them with assigning your `dbReader`?

Comment: Is that the **actual** code you're trying? I see at least a null pointer exception in there.

Comment: @Soner Gönül what you said didnt work out,would you please 4explain more?چ

Comment: Did you try executing the **exact** same SQL through some other tool, like a management tool for Oracle? Did that work?

Comment: And since you've already corrected at least one error in the posted code, how can we be sure you've reproduced the error in the posted code? Is it possible for you to just copy and paste the original unmodified code?

Comment: hi Lasse V. Karlsen :up code is original code. and Exception is in line :OleDbDataReader dbReader = (OleDbDataReader)dbCom.ExecuteReader(); and query is run to management tool for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the lines where you initialize the `dbReader`:

```
OleDbDataReader dbReader = (OleDbDataReader) dbCom.ExecuteReader();
```

The code you have now throws a `NullReferenceException` because you never initialize `dbReader`.

**UPDATE**: Now that the question is updated, this should no longer be the case...

Comment: hi i am reza rostami. i change camputer Cause to run code. i not understand problam why.
tanke you for all answer.